# Temporary password must be changed

Tags: php, mysql, password-recovery

When a user is having difficulty signing in, they enter their email address to recover their password. My php sends a temporary password (random long number, encrypted in db). However, I want them to be redirected to a page to change their password if it's a temporary one.

How do I know if it's a temporary password or not? What's the best way to do it + secure?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep a flag for each user in the database indicating if their password is temporary or not.

Comment: Thanks for your help! That's pretty straight forward than I originally thought!

Answer (score 1):

One obvious way of doing this is to maintain it in the `db`, in this case you have to make sure that you clear the db once the user changes the password successfully. Another way of doing it is to send user a secret link for users to reset the password instead of emailing a password which expires in a fixed time interval (depending on the req. and sensitivity of the data). The other approach in some cases is a little more secured way.